# Windows Python : Cannot launch (null) (null) because no install directory was specified

Tags: python, windows

When I try to lunch a python script on **Windows**, I get (python Myscript.py)

**Cannot launch (null) (null) because no install directory was specified**

python version used :

- 3.11
- 3.7
- 3.8
- 3.10

I removed the header (first line :D )  **#!/usr/bin/env python3** The python script is executed correctly
I don't know from where the problem is, because I have an other PC with the same python version and it's working on it.
In the future I can't remove this line (since the script will be shared with linux machines)

Comment: uh, did you figure this one out? Running into the same problem, windows 11. python 3.10.10